# AutoHotKey script to copy outlook email link and open email via Window CMD

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for a AutoHotKey script the will copy a highlighted email attachment link into Windows Run Diag (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and open the email. So far I have parts of what I want to work, but can't seem to get it all into one script to give the desired result.

These are my requirements and what I have so far to better understand my end goal:

**Requirements:**

1) Highlighted email attachment link from a browser

2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -- to copy the email attachment link from a browser

3) <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -- to open the Windows Run Diag

4) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> -- Paste the email attachment link into the Windows Run Diag

5) <kbd>Enter</kbd> -- to open the email

**AutoHotKey Script:**

```
$F10::    
Send, ^c  ; This command alone copy the email attachment link     
ClipWait     
FileDlg := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").FileRun, FileDlg := "" ; this command alone also open the Windows Run Diag    
Send, ^c{ENTER}    
return
```

Comment: If you do it manually (without using AutoHotKey), does Outlook open correctly with the "_email attachment link_"?

Comment: Your code seems to send a copy command to your run dialog, instead of a paste. Change the Send, ^c to Send, ^v

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a delay after opening the Run dialog? Also you could replace the comobjcreate with #r if you didn't have it disabled.

```
$F10::
Send, ^c
ClipWait
Send, #r
Sleep 100
Send, ^v{ENTER}
return
```